# SQLite3 - How can I assign Variables from the data returned from a SQL Query?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3-python

I'm a total Noob and don't know how I can assign variables to the data returned from a SQL Query so that I can then manipulate it. The example below captures random data and not the results from the SQL Query.
I'm using the Replit website with sqlite3.

```
    connect_SQL.execute(""" SELECT MAX(last),exchange from MY_TABLE WHERE base="XRP" and target="EUR" """)
    Sell_on=connect_SQL.fetchall() 
    Sell_price=last_price
    Sell_exchange=exchange
    print ("A: ", Sell_price , " B: ", Sell_exchange) # This doesnt work wrong value
    Print (Sell_on) # give output like [(0.3786567, 'EXMO') but I can assign variables to the price/exchange
```

All Help is appreciated!
The Price and Exchange details contained in Sell_on are correct, but combined into one output [(0.3786567, 'EXMO') I want to break this down and assign to two different variables, assigning one to the price (0.3786567) and the other to the exchange ('EXMO').

Comment: You should first work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.

Comment: Use `fetchone()` to fetch a single row of results. That will return a tuple of the columns, you can index this to get each field.

Comment: Note that this is not a valid SQL query. You're selecting `exchange` from a random row of the table, not the row with `MAX(last)`.